# How to avoid find command in Linux from throwing errors

Tags: linux

I know the way to delete older files using the find command is:

```
find /mydir/typ* -type f -mtime + 5 -delete
```

However if it doesn't find a file, it returns an error `saying no matches found`. Is there a way to just fail silently, i.e. not to throw an error if it can't find the file. If it does, delete it.

Comment: `man find` doesn't answer that for you?

Comment: @KenWhite I tried nowarn option but that didnt work

Answer (score 0):

```
find /mydir/typ* -type f -mtime + 5 -delete 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: I still get zsh: no matches found:

Comment: From documentation https://linux.die.net/man/1/find about nowarn parameter: Turn warning messages on or off. These warnings apply only to the command line usage, not to any conditions that find might encounter when it searches directories. The "2>" should redirect the stderr to the null device

Comment: Mmm, try with "&> /dev/null"

Answer (score 0):

So, from your comment on another answer, your *full* error is `zsh: no matches found`. *The error is coming from your shell, not `find`*.

`/mydir/typ*` is a shell glob, and zsh by default gives you an error if no files match the glob. [More info on that here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803/11750).

It's not clear what your directory structure and intended use are, but if you want to find files matching `typ*` in `/mydir`, you want `find /mydir -name 'typ*' -type f -mtime +5 -delete`. Otherwise, you'll have to be more specific about your situation.

Comment: Well now it doesnt throw an error, but it doesnt delete either!

Comment: @user1692342 - Probably because you missed the `-delete` part in find command!

Comment: That would be a problem with your find command. Did you include the rest of the command (`-type f -mtime + 5 -delete`) from your question? (You may need to remove the space between `+` and `5`)

Comment: @Kevin I have the delete command! And I tried without space as well!

Comment: It's really not feasible to debug further without more information about your folder structure and the specific file(s) you think it should delete but isn't. Run the command without the `-delete` to see which files it finds.

Answer (score 0):

`find` is executed in a subprocess, any errors are discarded, only the results get out to the command pipe:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -o pipefail
shopt -s extglob

_lsof() {
    local f="${1}" \
        inum
    inum="$(ls -i "$(readlink -f "${f}")" 2> /dev/null )" && \
    ( find /proc/+([0-9])/fd -follow -inum ${inum%% *} 2> /dev/null || : ) | \
        cut -f 3 -s -d '/' | \
        sort -n -u | \
        grep -sxvF "1"
}
```